# RegEx matching issue with IIS Rewrite Module

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to put a Regex match for a URL in IIS URL Rewrite module. The Regex matches perfectly outside the IIS (if i match it on any website with my URL) but it do not work in the IIS. I want to put a blockage on that URL actually.

Below is the Regex and my URL.

**Regex:**

```
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)[.,/(]guid[.,/']1a0aa5c3-1375-446e-9d69-c9eb4383a3ec[.,/'][.,/)]\/Items
```

**And the URL :**

```
http://example.com/ManagedPath/Site/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1a0aa5c3-1375-446e-9d69-c9eb4383a3ec')/Items
```

Do IIS Rewrite module handles the Regex differently? am i missing something?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.

Comment: That was very important point. Thanks Lex, i fixed it. Unfortunately its still not working in IIS, however the Regex is matching.

Comment: Try to check what FRT reveals, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Your first comment hit something in my mind and i am able to resolve the issue. Thank you very much mate. :)

Comment: Post your answer and accept it please.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
\/sitecollection\/site\/_api\/Web\/Lists(\()guid(\')b1a0aa5c3-1375-446e-9d69-c9eb4383a3ec(\')(\))(.*)
```

No need to add Host URL in your Regex.

Hope it will help someone.